# Changing app language on the fly in iOS

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsuserdefaults, swift2

I am new to iOS and I know this is a very frequently asked question, but I have found no appropriate answer for my query.

I have added text to controls on the app like this

```
        let productDescriptionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("textDescriptionCell") as! TextDescriptionCell
        productDescriptionCell.labelForCell.text = "Description"
        productDescriptionCell.labelForCell.sizeToFit()
        productDescriptionCell.labelForCell.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

like the 'Description' text above.

I want to have a button in my app, which lets the user change the language on the fly. I have found the following code as the most relevant but this requires an app restart.

```
userDefaults.setObject(["\(cc)"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

In addition, I have text hard coded in my storyboard controllers, I want those localized as well. How can I achieve this?

Thai and English are the languages I need localization for

```
productTitleCell.textFieldForCell.placeholder = SpecProvider.spec.localizedTuv(createLocalizedString("en", tuvEnglish: "Enter Title", tuvThai: "ป้อนชื่อ"))

    func localizedTuv(localizedString: LocalizedString) -> String {
    var locale = LocaleSelectionService.sharedInstance.getCachedLocale()
    if locale.isEmpty {
        locale = ""
    }
    switch(locale) {
        case "en": return localizedString.getTuvEnglish()
        case "th": return localizedString.getTuvThai()
        default: return localizedString.getTuvEnglish()
    }
}
```

I have tried the above code, but this could get very tedious. Please help, I am really stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create string files, and add the labels for every language you want to support. Once this is done you can use `NSLocalizedString` for the text used in your ViewController.

Here's a tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014